# Firefox touch scrolling

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, touch-screen

Firefox 67, Pop!_OS 18.04
When I try to scroll using my touchscreen, it just highlights whatever I hover over. It works fine in Chromium and in Chrome. I've been told to change `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` to 0, 1, and 2, but none of them worked. I've tried launching with `env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox` in terminal but it didn't work. Every question I've found online with a solution related to this is for Linux distros no later than Ubuntu 16 and Firefox no later than 43.